Cancel previous callback made from subscription ROS2
I'm new to ROS2 and I don't really know how to do this is in a clean way.
I'm in this condition
class CameraLocalisation(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('camera_localisation')
        # subscribe to topic
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            Localisation,
            'camera_localisation',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)

    def listener_callback(self, msg: Localisation):
        self.get_logger().info('CameraLocalisation: {}'.format(msg))
        # cancel previous loop
        # ....
        self.loop(msg)

I don't know if it is possible, but I wanted to know if there is a way of canceling old callback, the loop is an infinite loop that is need to be restarted after each messaged published on the topic subscribed.
I could it with a boolean value but I'm not sure that it is a safe maner to do it.
Thanks in advance for who is answering.

Is there any reason why you think it wouldn't be safe to do it with a Boolean? Have you tried it and did you experience any issues?
